# N-Computing:-Get Client IP of virtual desktops in php?

Tags: php, client-server

I am using N-Computing(N-Computing is hardware which create virtual desktops which enable multiple users to simultaneously share a single operating system instance.) server to run the project on LAN.

I run the system at client PC using server ip insted of localhost
 i.e.192.168.1.33/demo/demo.php .

My Problem is i want to fetch ip address of client PC using php code which run at server.

I tried some code which gives the ip address of server.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because with N-Computing, it actually creates multiple OS users on the same physical computer. In reality its like multiple users logged in onto one laptop/computer with different accounts. And as you might suspect, it means these users share the same hardware, mac addresses and ip address on all the network interfaces that they have.

If you do `ipconfig` on any of you users you will notice the ip address will always be `192.168.1.33`. This means PHP will give you the same IP address for all your logged in users..

That said, you could maybe give more information as to what exactly you want to achieve, so that we can suggest a workaround.

**EDIT**

To get different IPs please try [NComputing IP Utility](http://www.cdcbrasil.com.br/ncomputing/downloads/guide_niu_userguide.pdf), this will give different ips for your clients, THEN you can use the php script.

`echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

to get the IP address of the user.....

Comment: i just want to provide ip based login to the users. and  i get the same ip over all the pc in network when i check it using ipconfig. But in the setting of N-Computing i saw the different ip's for all users i am trying to retrieve  that ips. Is there any other way to provide ip based login to the users.

Comment: No problem, @SagarRajput...Don't forget: you can accept this answer if it was the correct solution :)